# Use External URL to point to Local Server, Locally

Tags: dns, ip, subdomain, raspberry-pi

I want to be able to access my raspberry pi locally using the dynamic dns name I have setup but I am having some trouble.

Example:

**pi.domain.com** - this can be accessed from outside the network fine, it updates the IP dynamically etc.

When accessing **pi.domain.com** from inside my local network, the same one the RPi is on, I cant do it (timeout).

If I use **raspberrypi/** or **192.168.1.72** I can access it from my network internally, :22 access etc.

My question is: would it be possible to configure something so that when I am local to the RPi, I can use **pi.domain.com** and it will resolve to **raspberrypi/**?

Thanks, 
Adam

Comment: Im interested too. This has something to do with dns. But I never had the time to dig deeper. But as a topleveldomain is mapped to an (public)IP and, as I guess, you are sitting behind a NAT Router, this will be a little more tricky. Because outside the lan the domain would point to the router which is just port forwarding to the pi. And inside the domain points to the rPI. But however you should be able to access pi.domain.com from the lan too, as the gateway will forward the dns lookup to the inet, get its own ip back and forward further packets to the pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple solution I'm afraid. All I did was port forward :80 to my RPi in my routers settings, boom. Thought it would be a bit harder than that... I won't delete this just encase anyone else doing the same comes across this.

I thought that as the Pi was in the routers DMZ it would have done this automatically... oh well!

Comment: I excluded this possibility because you said that you can acces the pi from outside. Which needs port forwarding too. Remember that port 80 is just for html. You have to forward the port for every service you need, e.g. to get ssh acces you need to forward port 22 too. You can lookup the service-port mapping on [IANAs website](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)

Comment: Yeah I have port 22 and 80 forwarded to the Pi at the moment, will forward ports for any other services as and when. Works for me!